# Duplicate values in column

Tags: perl

I have a original file which has following columns,

```
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,1000
02-May-2018,C,Sell,0.25,2000
02-May-2018,JPM,Sell,0.25,3000
02-May-2018,WFC,Sell,0.25,5000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,7000
02-May-2018,GOOG,Sell,0.25,8000
02-May-2018,GOOG,Sell,0.25,9000
02-May-2018,C,Sell,0.25,2000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,3000
```

I am trying to print this original line if I see value in the second column more then 2 times.. for example, if I see AAPL more then 2 times desired result should print

```
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,1000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,7000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,3000
```

So Far, I have written the following which prints results multiple times which is wrong.. can you please help on what I am doing wrong?

```
open (FILE, "<$TMPFILE") or die "Could not open $TMPFILE";
open (OUT, ">$TMPFILE1") or die "Could not open $TMPFILE1";
%count = ();
@symbol = ();
while ($line = <FILE>)
{
        chomp $line;
        (@data) = split(/,/,$line);
         $count{$data[1]}++;
        @keys = sort {$count{$a} cmp $count{$b}} keys %count;
        for my $key (@keys)
        {
        if ( $count{$key} > 2 )
        {
            print "$line\n";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to remember which ones you have seen and only print new ones. You could do that by simply only printing the first time you see it after it's more than 2.

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;` are really good things.

Comment: So basically you want the same file as the input, but with lines whose column 2 values appear twice or less removed?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. but I am not looking for printing original line if value in second column is present more then 2 times...

Comment: @Efficasy: Then I don't understand. That's what the sample output in your question contains, and you say *"I am trying to print this original line if I see value in the second column more then 2 times."* which says the opposite.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that, if the value in second column occurs more then 2 times then print the entire line..

Comment: By "then print the entire line" I guess you really meant "then print all the lines with that value in the second column".

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this - store lines you've seen in a 'buffer' and print them out again if the condition is hit (before continuing to print as you go):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %buffer; 
my %count_of;

while ( my $line = <> ) {  
   my ( $date, $ticker, @values ) = split /,/, $line; 
   #increment the count
   $count_of{$ticker}++;

   if ( $count_of{$ticker} < 3 ) { 
       #count limit not hit, so stash the current line in the buffer. 
       $buffer{$ticker} .= $line; 
       next;
   }
   #print the buffer if the count has been hit
   if ( $count_of{$ticker} == 3 ) {
       print $buffer{$ticker};
   }
   #only gets to here once the limit is hit, so just print normally.
   print $line;
}
```

With your input data, this outputs:

```
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,1000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,7000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
push @{ $lines{(split",")[1]} }, $_ while <>;
print @{ $lines{$_} } for grep @{ $lines{$_} } > 2, sort keys %lines;

perl program.pl inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the input file twice, because you don't know the final counts until you get to the end of the file

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($TMPFILE, $TMPFILE1) = qw/ infile outfile /;

my %counts;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $TMPFILE or die "Could not open $TMPFILE: $!";

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my @fields = split /,/;
        ++$counts{$fields[1]};
    }
}

open my $fh, '<', $TMPFILE or die "Could not open $TMPFILE: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $TMPFILE1 or die "Could not open $TMPFILE1: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
        my @fields = split /,/;
        print $out_fh $_ if $counts{$fields[1]} > 2;
}
```

#### output

```
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,1000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,7000
02-May-2018,AAPL,Sell,0.25,3000
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, "<$TMPFILE") or die "Could not open $TMPFILE";
open (OUT, ">$TMPFILE1") or die "Could not open $TMPFILE1";

my %data;
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @line = split /,/, $line;
    push(@{$data{$line[1]}}, $line); 
}

foreach my $key (keys %data) {
    if(@{$data{$key}} > 2) {
        print "$_\n" foreach  @{$data{$key}};
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one in OP post, but I am updating my answer

Comment: You also need to `print` to (or `select`) the `OUT` file handle, and should really be using lexical file handles and the three-parameter `open`.

Comment: @Borodin, I am writing an aswer to solve the problem that OP is having which is to print out correct data. Printing on the screen or the file, I am sure OP can figure out himself. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It seems rather shabby to present a "solution" and also tell the OP that they need to fix any remaining bugs. Your answer should be high-quality and bug-free as it is likely to be used by many people as an example. Please don't shirk your responsibilities.

Comment: I guess I should point out that nowhere in the OP it says that the data should be prinited into the file. Just because there is an opened filehandle for writing, does not mean this data goes there. You assume it should be printed there.